# Free open source paint program for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, image-editor

I need a program to:

- Paste a screenshot taken with the Print Screen key
- Crop the picture
- Draw a bit with the mouse, maybe add some text
- Works on Windows 7 and all later versions

Further requirements:

- Gratis and open source
- Preferably under 10 MB to download, the smaller the better
- Straightforward to use for any user

Comment: MSPaint complies with all of this (except being open source) and is bundled in every version of Windows since a few decades ago, up to the newest Windows 10. I don't see any reason to change it for now, if it complies what you need.

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean "it doesn't work" or "you should stop using it". It means that it's essentially a "finished" product - no further development or enhancement will be done - and it _might_ be replaced by another product in the future - but for now, it's still fine to use. You shouldn't _rely_ on it being there in the future - but while it's still there, it's fine for use.

Comment: That said, what have you looked at and rejected? I can find about a half-dozen possibilities at https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-paint/?license=opensource , but I haven't used any of them, and can't therefore make an actual recommendation.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Yes I looked at that page yesterday and tried the first one, it is far too big (80MB) and complex for my purpose.

Comment: If it was not for open-source, I would recommend the [FastStone Image Viewer](http://faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm).

Comment: @martinstoeckli , think you are referring to [Fast stone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm)

Comment: @nichilas Raoul, will  **snip it** will work for you

Comment: @Bijujose - Since the OP asked to paste a _PrtScn_ image, the image viewer will do and it is for free.

Comment: I removed the reference to Microsoft's product since it is not open source anyway.

Comment: Just curious as to why you need the source code.

Comment: @Mawg: Customer computers, I must avoid any form of call-home/tracking feature.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (+1), and good luck with the code review :-)

Comment: Then, if you agree with @Alejandro that MS Paint fits your needs, can't you just use that? You can probably trust MS, and there ought to be an MD5 somewhere

Comment: @Mawg: yes, that's an option I have indeed.

Answer (score 2):

[PhotoDemon](http://photodemon.org/) seems a good fit

1. You can paste a screenshot or an image
2. It's open source and free
3. You can draw with pencil / add text
4. Works from XP to Windows 10
5. Portable as well :)
6. Straightforward if you have used any other image editor like MS Paint or Paint.NET
7. You can use batch operations & macros

The only requirement it doesn't meet is the size as it is 12 MB to download.

[image]

[2-Clause BSD License](https://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php)

Answer (score 2):

with your requirements [**Pinta**](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/) comes in my mind, which is a FOSS cross-platform fork of paint.NET 3.
it seems to me, that it fits your bill:

- for sure raster graphics can be pasted
- copping, selecting, moving, etc. is supported
- painting with different styles, coloring, erasing and inserting text etc. is supported
- is cross-platform and works on windows, linux, mac, bsd (relies on mono and gtk)
- is free as in beer and speech
- [its downloads](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/releases) are less than 3 MB
- if you are familiar with Paint it won't be hard to get used to Pinta

let me mention some additional features:

- has a color-picker
- has a exemption tool
- has a bunch of filters
- can work with layers
- lists the history of your actions in a nice way

[image]

MIT License

Comment: The problem with Pinta is that it is abandoned. No updates since 3 years ago.

Comment: @Sonamor: if you have a look at [its github-site](https://github.com/PintaProject/Pinta) you will see, that Pinta is still active, although its development is really slow... so yes, its a pity that there is no stable release since 3 years, but if you will/can not compile a recent version yourself, you can try the development build also available at its [homepage](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/releases).

Comment: What about being able to run on win 7 and later? If it hasn’t been updated in awhile, this means there has been no active development to make sure it works with newer OSes. I recently came across software like this that I was unable to install in windows 7 because of the age.